# Call a method in a PHP class from wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a separate PHP class called MyClass.php. I need to call a method in that class and send it a variable. This is what I have in functions.php:

```
function email_submission($entry, $form){
    MyClass::addEmail($entry["2"]);
}

//Fatal error: Class 'MyClass' not found in /path/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try including your class file with `require` or `include` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add this line `require_once 'MyClass.php';`